# Firefox toolbarbutton context ( right click menu on toolbar )

Tags: firefox, firefox-addon, xul

In Chrome, its possible to make context menu items for extension icons, like this:

[image]

What is the best and cleanest way to emulate that in Firefox - preferably using the standard toolbar and standard toolbarbuttons.

```
<toolbarpalette id="BrowserToolbarPalette">
    <toolbarbutton class="toolbarbutton-1"
                   label="My button"
                   oncommand="doSomething()" />
</toolbarpalette>
```

Comment: Are you using SDK? If not then you are using CustomizableUI.jsm to add button to toolbar right? So now on right click of that you want to show a custom menu? This is easily possible with the `onBuild` porition of the CustimizableUI.jsm. In the `onBuild` set `popup` attribute on your button to the id of a menupopup element you create and add as a child of it. I'll try to write an example. Based on this: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/JavaScript_code_modules/CustomizableUI.jsm#CreateWidget_-_Custom_Type_-_Simple

Comment: No, im just using the snippet above to add a normal button and overlay it over the UI. But moving to CustomizableUI does make sense.

Comment: Using CustomizableUI is an excellent choice, it allows the user freedom to drop it anywhere, and you can really customize your built elements to behave however you want.

Comment: The sample above does allow for customisation via the customizer but not menus :) I'm trying to get a good example to use it in a overlay extension.

Comment: In the `onBuild` section you can create whatever your mind can dream of. And it it is build and wrapped in an invisible box giving it the full customization of any of the standard CustomizlbeUI elements. Heres some custom stuff: https://gist.github.com/Noitidart/10902477

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's some piece of cake code that does what you need:

```
CustomizableUI.createWidget({
    id: 'noida',
    defaultArea: CustomizableUI.AREA_NAVBAR,
    label: 'My Widget',
    tooltiptext: 'This is my widget created with CUI.jsm',
    onCreated: function(aNode) {
        console.info('aNode:', aNode);
        aNode.setAttribute('image', 'chrome://branding/content/icon16.png');

        var myMenuJson = [
                            'xul:menupopup', {id: 'my_btns_pop'},
                                ['xul:menuitem', {label: 'menu item1'}],
                                ['xul:menu', {label: 'menu item2 is submenu1'},
                                    ['xul:menupopup', {},
                                        ['xul:menuitem', {label: 'submenu1 item1'}],
                                        ['xul:menuitem', {label: 'submenu1 item2'}],
                                        ['xul:menuitem', {label: 'submenu1 item3'}]
                                    ]
                                ],
                                ['xul:menuitem', {label: 'menu item3 is before a seperator'}],
                                ['xul:menuseparator', {}],
                                ['xul:menuitem', {label: 'menu item4 is after a seperator'}]
                        ];
        aNode.appendChild(jsonToDOM(myMenuJson, aNode.ownerDocument, {}));
        aNode.setAttribute('contextmenu', 'my_btns_pop');
    }
});
```

This uses the `jsonToDOM` function from MDN here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/Overlay_Extensions/XUL_School/DOM_Building_and_HTML_Insertion#JSON_Templating

If you want to copy and paste the code and run in scratchpad, copy paste this code, it has the jsonToDom function copied and pasted in:

```
function jsonToDOM(json, doc, nodes) {

    var namespaces = {
        html: 'http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml',
        xul: 'http://www.mozilla.org/keymaster/gatekeeper/there.is.only.xul'
    };
    var defaultNamespace = namespaces.html;

    function namespace(name) {
        var m = /^(?:(.*):)?(.*)$/.exec(name);        
        return [namespaces[m[1]], m[2]];
    }

    function tag(name, attr) {
        if (Array.isArray(name)) {
            var frag = doc.createDocumentFragment();
            Array.forEach(arguments, function (arg) {
                if (!Array.isArray(arg[0]))
                    frag.appendChild(tag.apply(null, arg));
                else
                    arg.forEach(function (arg) {
                        frag.appendChild(tag.apply(null, arg));
                    });
            });
            return frag;
        }

        var args = Array.slice(arguments, 2);
        var vals = namespace(name);
        var elem = doc.createElementNS(vals[0] || defaultNamespace, vals[1]);

        for (var key in attr) {
            var val = attr[key];
            if (nodes && key == 'id')
                nodes[val] = elem;

            vals = namespace(key);
            if (typeof val == 'function')
                elem.addEventListener(key.replace(/^on/, ''), val, false);
            else
                elem.setAttributeNS(vals[0] || '', vals[1], val);
        }
        args.forEach(function(e) {
            try {
                elem.appendChild(
                                    Object.prototype.toString.call(e) == '[object Array]'
                                    ?
                                        tag.apply(null, e)
                                    :
                                        e instanceof doc.defaultView.Node
                                        ?
                                            e
                                        :
                                            doc.createTextNode(e)
                                );
            } catch (ex) {
                elem.appendChild(doc.createTextNode(ex));
            }
        });
        return elem;
    }
    return tag.apply(null, json);
}

CustomizableUI.createWidget({
    id: 'noida',
    defaultArea: CustomizableUI.AREA_NAVBAR,
    label: 'My Widget',
    tooltiptext: 'This is my widget created with CUI.jsm',
    onCreated: function(aNode) {
        console.info('aNode:', aNode);
        aNode.setAttribute('image', 'chrome://branding/content/icon16.png');

        var myMenuJson = [
                            'xul:menupopup', {id: 'my_btns_pop'},
                                ['xul:menuitem', {label: 'menu item1'}],
                                ['xul:menu', {label: 'menu item2 is submenu1'},
                                    ['xul:menupopup', {},
                                        ['xul:menuitem', {label: 'submenu1 item1'}],
                                        ['xul:menuitem', {label: 'submenu1 item2'}],
                                        ['xul:menuitem', {label: 'submenu1 item3'}]
                                    ]
                                ],
                                ['xul:menuitem', {label: 'menu item3 is before a seperator'}],
                                ['xul:menuseparator', {}],
                                ['xul:menuitem', {label: 'menu item4 is after a seperator'}]
                        ];
        aNode.appendChild(jsonToDOM(myMenuJson, aNode.ownerDocument, {}));
        aNode.setAttribute('contextmenu', 'my_btns_pop');
    }
});
```

And of course to destory your button element do this code:

```
CustomizableUI.destroyWidget('noida');
```

Comment: I have a addon which have created for some specific usage it works perfectly fine but not sure how to add as a widget and which folder to place those files on the mozilla source code to build the browser

Comment: Trying to pack a mozilla version with some addons as a widgets

Comment: Sorry Richie man it's been a long time. And I think the above was applicable to non-webextensions. I think all extensions in Firefox are now webextensions.

Comment: was looking to build something like this https://github.com/cliqz-oss/browser-f where they get modules as widgets from this repo https://github.com/cliqz-oss/browser-core. Was not sure where the modules where placed on the browser